# Sqlserver predict top5 records but various group - mathematical logic

Tags: sql-server, math, logic

I have table like below,

```
user_id     Task_name      Score
__________________________________
1             101            10
1             102            9
1             103            8
2             104           10
2             105            9
3             106            9
4             107            9
4             108            8
5             109            8
5             110            7
5             111            6
6             112           10
6             113            9
6             114            8
7             115            9
7             116            8
```

I want to take top 5 score or max 5 Tasks.

Condition:

1) At least try to get one Tasks from one user.

Output:

```
    User_Id    Task_Name    Score
____________________________________
    1             101         10
    2             104         10
    6             112         10
    3             106          9
    4             107          9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT TOP 5 User_id, Task_name, Score
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY Score DESC) R
    FROM Src
) T
ORDER BY R, Score DESC, user_id
```

It yields:

```
User_Id    Task_Name    Score
____________________________________
    1             101         10
    2             104         10
    6             112         10
    3             106          9
    4             107          9
```

If you need top 5 ordered, wrap results with another `SELECT..ORDER` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 5 user_id, Task_name, Score
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY Score DESC) R
        FROM Src
    ) T
    ORDER BY R, Score DESC, user_id
) E
ORDER BY Score DESC, user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select top 5 t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by score desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by score desc;
```

The `row_number()` is used to select the best row for each user.  The outer query then chooses the top 5 users with the tasks.

Comment: But it is always taking whose seqnum is 1. I need minimum 5 tasks.

Comment: It is returning the top 5 distinct users, which appears to be what the question asks for.